# How to Make Male Lactation More Common

Tags: biology, humans

Though the job of breastfeeding is typically known to the women, there are documented cases of men producing breast milk.  However, these reports are few and far between, which means that while men do have the ability to produce milk, it doesn't happen often.

Let's say that in an alternate universe, male lactation is as routine as female lactation without the use of fertility drugs or breast pumps.  Would this require a change in male anatomy?  If yes, how?

Comment: You need to read this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynecomastia, especially the "causes" section.

Comment: I don't want to read your story.

Comment: Seems like a good question to me. If male lactation is to become routine and ordinary, what has to happen to male anatomy? Wish I could provide an answer, but....

Comment: Man, this is more gross than the execution via acid question.

Comment: If evolution selected for human males to breast-feed children as human females do, then men would have breasts as well developed as women. A large volume of milk requires a large volume of lactating tissue, which means sizable breasts. But it's hard to see why human evolution would produce males that can breast feed. Females only breast-feeding is common to all mammals. So you're suggesting not merely a change to human evolution, but to mammalian evolution in general.

Comment: @Lensman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Male_lactation

Comment: @JohnWDailey: (a) Very well, your citation identifies one single species in which male mammals do breast-feed. But humans are specialized by evolution into males hunting and fighting, and females for gathering and child-rearing. A change to that situation would have pretty widespread ramifications. The human species has obviously done well by having the genders differentiate (altho in modern societies, women aren't happy about it).

Comment: (b) I have read with interest stories, and role-playing game scenarios, in which there is an intelligent species evolved from dinosaurs. With egg layers, females aren't handicapped by pregnancy, so true equality of the sexes in possible. Possible in a way that it will never be with humans. In my opinion (not fact, opinion), if you changed the human species that much, we would no longer be human. We'd be a different species.

Comment: @Lensman  The citation ALSO states reports of MEN breastfeeding, but they were few and sporadic.  The whole point of the question is how to make male lactation as common as female lactation.

Comment: @JohnWDailey: Okay, but my point is that we need to restate the question as: What evolutionary pressures would cause natural selection to select for human male breast-feeding, and what evolutionary changes would result? Whatever those pressures are, they're certainly going to produce large mammary glands on men as the norm, for the same reason it produces large mammary glands on women as the norm. You can't have one without the other.

Comment: As far as I know a very small part of the breast actually produces milk, the rest is just fat. In fact even women with very small breast can breastfeed. So men in this world will be very similar to us

Comment: not all societies have the same gender roles, there are places where women ''hunt'' and males take care of kids and there are societies where the roles are spread equally... that's not evolution neither  biology this is how people are used to think. Big breasts have nothing to do with milk production, the breast size is a sexually selected thing... technically and practically it is a fact that  even completely flat-chested women can breastfeed perfectly without any problem.

Comment: @Lensman It's a myth that larger breasts produce more milk. Breasts evolved so that the baby is less likely to suffocate while feeding(and later through sexual selection).

Comment: That is not true. Even flat chested women can breastfeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It requires no change in male anatomy other than what a biological father already has present.  The change would be in culture.  Among the Aka, of whom all fathers wet nurse their children when their wives forage, it is far more common for (a percentage of) men to actually produce milk for their child.  While it is considered just this side of immoral in America several new fathers have 'anonymously' reported having the ability to lactate after wet nursing their children for a period of time.. One documented the agony of having milk upon being called to serve in the military overseas.  These were all biological men without artificial hormones given.

Comment: Do you have any sources?  I'd love to know more, and verification is always a bonus.

Comment: you also need ot make food easier to get, in hunter gatherer settings males only have limited time with young infants since new mothers and pregant women have limited ability to find food the male needs to spend a lot of time away from mother and child finding food.

Answer (score 3):

No change in anatomy is required as male breast already have everything needed to produce milk expect the stimulus which can be recreated easily. All men have milk ducts, mammary tissue plus  oxytocin and prolactin which are the hormones needed to produce milk.

You only need to make  changes in society, many people consider it gross for males to breastfeed their kids some people even consider gross for women to breastfeed their kids(they probably think kids don't need food and they can just do photosynthesis).

Some tribes in Africa have fathers regularly breastfeeding at least 47%  the time mothers do, apparently all fathers do it.

When some people consider the men of this tribes to be the best Fathers in the world some other people consider them not only gross but, also accuse them of child abuse.

Simply change the society and remove the grossness.Afterwards males will naturally realize how their boobs are perfectly functional, and they can use it to build more profound bounds with their children.

Comment: [Comma splices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)… Know how to divide the text into sentences, and it will be much nicer to read.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not require a change in anatomy, as you seem to already know from your remarks that it happens sometimes as it is.

Comment: But how do I make it MORE COMMON?  That's where I'm going.

Comment: Your (only) question is "Would this require a change in male anatomy? If yes, how?"  you can edit your question to clarify, and (seeing the negative score) maybe make it more attractive for this site.  See the Sandbox on meta.

Comment: Edit the question how?

Comment: Why is your previous remark necessary? Make the question text reflect what you really want to know.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: "But how do I make it MORE COMMON? That's where I'm going."  That should be what the Question post is asking!  Your need for a comment indicates that the text of the question is not clear or not what you really meant.

Comment: Didn't you read the part where it says, "Let's say that in an alternate universe, male lactation is as routine as female lactation without the use of fertility drugs or breast pumps"?

Comment: As I understand it, to make it more common, you just need to alter the male hormone balance.

Comment: Yes, that's an assumption or precondition of the question. Not *the* question.  We're assuming that part, not addressing it.  It *is* more common. How to make it more common is not being asked.  Your question is **not** how to make it more common, but what that means to anatomy. See another comment to your original post.

Answer (score -1):

### More estrogen

There are all kinds of environmental factors that could raise estrogen levels in men - this would result in enlarged male breasts and facilitate lactation.

A particular case in our world is bisphenol-A, a plastic additive that was earlier used in food containers, and entering the body it acts similarly to estrogen and causing the abovementioned issues.

This or some other chemical contaminant, or some bacterial/fungal infection that produces estrogen as a byproduct, or factory farming pumping food animals full of hormones are all plausible ways to cause what you intend - in absence of control and regulation of food mass production, such factors can change the hormonal balance in most of population and achieve these changes in male physique.

Comment: women with flat chests can produce as much milk as women with boobs like the ones of Annie Hawkins-Turner  or bigger. So why do men need boobs to produce milk?

Comment: @Charon estrogen is a hormone that happens to have a wide variety of effects even post-puberty, one of them is triggering gynecomastia (enlarged breasts) in men, another is (together with prolactin) facilitating lactation. While breast size is largely determined by hormone levels during puberty, the hormonal effects of pregnancy will temporarily increase breast size in any woman; the same hormones (if they are somehow introduced) will also increase breast size in men.